# Import/Export wallet vi bitcoin-cli. Bitcoin abc node

Tags: ecash

I'd like move my bitcoin cash wallet from one server to the other using the cli.

Server 1: bitcoin abc: 0.17.2.
Server 2: bitcoin abc: 0.18.0

I have done the following:

1. ran the command: backupwwallet "myfile.dat" on server 1 successfully.
2. copy the "myfile.dat" to server 2.
3. rand the command: importwallet "myfile.dat".

I get the following the error when trying to import the wallet:

```
error code: -8
error message:
Cannot open wallet dump file.
```

I have also tried to replace stop the node on server 2 and copy the wallet.dat over to the other server and then start the wallet up again on server 2. 
I get the following error in the logs:

```
CDBEnv::Open: LogDir=/home/cryptodaemon/.bitcoincash/database ErrorFile=/home/cryptodaemon/.bitcoincash/db.log
2018-09-09 07:48:21 Failed to rename wallet.dat to wallet.dat.1536479301.bak
```

How can I move the wallet from one server to another?
Could anyone give me pointers in doing this?

Comment: For future readers: the Bitcoin-ABC client is (confusingly) not a Bitcoin client.

Answer (score 2):

`importwallet` is the opposite RPC of `dumpwallet`, not `backupwallet`.

`backupwallet` creates a copy of your wallet.dat file. You restore that file by putting it back in the data directory.

`dumpwallet` creates a wallet dump (just private keys, no history, addresses, labels, accounts, ...), which can be imported into an existing wallet using `importwallet`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is Bitcoin ABC's bug. As an alternative to `backupwallet`, [`dumpwallet`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/wallet/dumpwallet/) might work.

In addition, please file a bug report at https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check which database version the various abc -qt wallets use as their backend.  Any change will prevent using the old one from writing a wallet.dat suitable for the new one.  To do what you are doing, I'm on step 2 of
- create an account at a reputable exchange
- do a small test transaction to check that your coin gets there
- do another small test transaction to check that you can get coin back to your new wallet
- move your coin from home to the exchange 
- move your coin from the exchange to your new wallet at home
That is four transaction fees just because someone thought that bdb4.8 was too samey to keep the same.